# ASP.NET MVC Database localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, dependency-injection

I'm developing an multilingual enterprise web site and I would like to store the localization in database.

I have read the following article which is very good but I personally think that is a an overhead and I can achieve the same much easy:

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)

I have already setup some ground but I'm not sure if my approach is fine. Basically I have created a service that is registers with DI.

```
public interface ILocalizedStringProvider
{
    string GetLocalizedString(string key);

    string GetLocalizedString(string key, string deafultValue);
}
```

Also i have created a Html helper like this

```
public static MvcHtmlString LocalizedString(this HtmlHelper helper, string key, string defaultValue)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue)) return new MvcHtmlString("");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return new MvcHtmlString(defaultValue);

        ILocalizedStringProvider localizedStringProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILocalizedStringProvider>();

        if (localizedStringProvider == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(defaultValue);
        }

        string val = localizedStringProvider.GetLocalizedString(key, defaultValue);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(defaultValue);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(val);
    }
```

Then the helper is simply invoked from the view.

First I want to know if this approach is good and if is not an anti-pattern.

Second my concern is this line:

```
ILocalizedStringProvider localizedStringProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILocalizedStringProvider>();
```

Is it maybe better to resolve the service ILocalizedStringProvider in the controller with constructor injection and let the controller populate the ViewBag with the localization's?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing localization in the DB?

Comment: It is a requirement, there is a separate application for the translation team

Comment: @weirdo - why do they need an application?  Why can't they just edit the html and give you localized views?  After all, you typically have to change the size of fields to accommodate different sized words.

Comment: Well two things fist is that the application is dynamically growing in versions and is hard to give the views to translate on each new release and second the translator are not technical found off so it was an PM decision to make their job easy and with less errors for both sides.

Comment: Why not simply use the Resource files, they are really good a doing this, and non technical person can easily edit them. You will do database round-trip only to get localized strings?

Answer (score 2):

You can use my Griffin.MvcContrib project. It contains a ready to use MS SqlServer implementation for storing localization in the database.

Introduction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri

**Administration**

There is also an adminstration area which you can use to manage the localizations:

[image]

**SQL Server setup**

https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib/wiki/SqlServer

**Source code**

The project is available at github: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I have found your project previously and decided not to use it because the core implementation requires my controllers to be inherited from your base controller. Since MVC has a very good feature the Action filters I relay don't want to use the base controller concept.

Comment: You got it wrong. I do not require you to inherit a base controller.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very good one : 
http://west-wind.com/westwind.globalization/

It offers :

- DB storage
- Resx Import/Export
- Strong Type Class generation

it is rapidly added to your projects via Nuget, and you have the Full Source Code.. Awesome stuff